# Iterate over loop with append data continuous

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

I need to iterate over row data in a pandas dataframe. However, I am stuck with looping because spending much time on millions data. I think my code still is not optimal.

```
new_columns = ['alt', 'alt_anomaly']
df_new = pd.DataFrame(columns=new_columns)
loop = 20
idx = 0

for i, row in df.iterrows():
    for alt in range(loop):
        alt_anomaly = df.iloc[i]['alt'] * (400.00)
        df_new.loc[idx] = row.values.tolist() + [alt_anomaly]
        idx += 1

print(df_new)
```

Use 400 ft as multiples to gradually change on the first vector, the second by 800 feet, and so on by multiple.

```
its like 
row[1] = 27800+400
row[2] = 27775+800
etc....
```

Thanks for your help, I appreciate that.

Comment: What is 'alt_anomaly' and your expected output?

Comment: have you tried `df_new['alt_anomaly'] = df_new['alt'].apply(lambda x:x*2)` ?

Comment: @RuthgerRighart continuously, like df['alt_anomaly'] row 1 +400, row 2 +800, etc

Comment: @AmriRasyidi thanks for your time, when i executed it its not continuously sir

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following without looping:

```
df['alt_anomaly'] = df['alt'] + (df.index+1)*400
```

Or use Pandas .add [option](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add.html#pandas.DataFrame.add):

```
df['alt'].add((df.index+1)*400)
```

Comment: It's my pleasure!